# Determine the type of the differential equation $e^{-y}(1+ \dot y)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Hey Guys I have the following to do:

Equation: $$e^{-y}(1+ \dot y)=1$$

a) Determine the type of the differential equation  (is it linear/nonlinear, separable/non-separable, homogeneous/non-homogeneous)?

b) Find the particular solution subject to the initial condition $y(0) = –\ln 2$.

c) Plot the solution in the interval $t \in [–5, 5]$.

So far I understand that the equation is non linear, and non separable however I am not quite sure.
With the rest of the question I am pulling complete blanks. Any tips where to start? Cheers

Comment: Is it written correctly? it is not a DEQ as written.

Comment: I do not see any differential equation here. Any typo ?

Comment: following that I have found the equation to be separable. Is this correct?

Comment: @Robert: **Hint:** This is a Separable Differential Equation.